# sonar-maven-plugin fails because of invalid checkstyle.xml (The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed)

Tags: java, xml, maven, sonarqube, checkstyle

I use Maven 3.2.1 and SonarQube 4.5 in conjunction with Checkstyle 5.6. Executing

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

works fine for some projects, but others fail with "Can not execute Checkstyle: unable to read ... checkstyle.xml - unable to parse configuration stream - The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed". Here's the output:

```
### ~\.mavenrc
### Set JAVA_HOME for maven to /opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.7.0_67
### Set MAVEN_OPTS to -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cc4-common 4.14.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) @ cc4-common ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.5
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /srv/build/jenkins/jobs/cc4-trunk/workspace/trunk/cc4-   common/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5
[INFO] [13:09:54.973] Load global referentials...
[INFO] [13:09:55.122] Load global referentials done: 151 ms
[INFO] [13:09:55.134] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [13:09:55.145] Install plugins
[INFO] [13:09:55.268] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [13:09:55.278] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?   useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
[INFO] [13:09:57.034] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [13:09:58.837] Load project referentials...
[INFO] [13:09:59.766] Load project referentials done: 929 ms
[INFO] [13:09:59.766] Load project settings
[INFO] [13:10:00.806] Loading technical debt model...
[INFO] [13:10:00.838] Loading technical debt model done: 32 ms
[INFO] [13:10:00.843] Apply project exclusions
[INFO] [13:10:01.201] -------------  Scan cc4-common
[INFO] [13:10:01.206] Load module settings
[INFO] [13:10:02.293] Loading rules...
[INFO] [13:10:02.888] Loading rules done: 595 ms
[INFO] [13:10:02.907] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [13:10:03.161] Compare to previous analysis (2014-10-06)
[INFO] [13:10:03.217] Compare over 30 days (2014-09-13, analysis of 2014-09-13    02:44:12.0)
[INFO] [13:10:03.237] Compare to previous version (2014-07-16)
[INFO] [13:10:03.238] No quality gate is configured.
[INFO] [13:10:03.366] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [13:10:03.367] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 1 ms
[INFO] [13:10:03.367] Base dir: /srv/build/jenkins/jobs/cc4-trunk/workspace/trunk/cc4-   common
[INFO] [13:10:03.367] Working dir: /srv/build/jenkins/jobs/cc4-trunk/workspace/trunk/cc4-common/target/sonar
[INFO] [13:10:03.368] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] [13:10:03.368] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] [13:10:03.368] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] [13:10:03.368] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [13:10:03.368] Index files
[INFO] [13:10:03.378] Excluded sources: 
[INFO] [13:10:03.378]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [13:10:04.074] 431 files indexed
[INFO] [13:10:08.941] Quality profile for java: SE-Tools 3.2 (with Findbugs)
[INFO] [13:10:09.281] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [13:10:09.429] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] [13:10:09.434] 273 source files to be analyzed
[ERROR] [13:10:09.873] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:09.891] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:09.934] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:10.134] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:10.267] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:10.296] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:10.778] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:11.121] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:11.452] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:11.491] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:11.515] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:11.574] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:11.576] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:11.632] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:11.658] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:11.690] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:11.699] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:12.654] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:12.668] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:12.687] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:12.712] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:13.052] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.089] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.140] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.182] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.307] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.349] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.375] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.393] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:13.466] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:15.425] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:15.475] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:15.501] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:15.516] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:15.533] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:15.538] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:15.577] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:15.591] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [13:10:15.604] Class not found: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] [13:10:15.613] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[INFO] [13:10:15.615] 273/273 source files analyzed
[INFO] [13:10:15.666] Java Main Files AST scan done: 6237 ms
[INFO] [13:10:15.672] Java bytecode scan...
[INFO] [13:10:16.374] Java bytecode scan done: 702 ms
[INFO] [13:10:16.375] Java Test Files AST scan...
[INFO] [13:10:16.375] 158 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [13:10:17.124] 158/158 source files analyzed
[INFO] [13:10:17.124] Java Test Files AST scan done: 749 ms
[INFO] [13:10:17.182] Package design analysis...
[INFO] [13:10:17.414] Package design analysis done: 232 ms
[INFO] [13:10:18.041] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 8759 ms
[INFO] [13:10:18.045] Sensor QProfileSensor...
[INFO] [13:10:18.049] Sensor QProfileSensor done: 4 ms
[INFO] [13:10:18.049] Sensor FindbugsSensor...
[INFO] [13:10:18.061] Execute Findbugs 3.0.0...
[INFO] [13:10:19.885] Findbugs output report: /srv/build/jenkins/jobs/cc4-trunk/workspace/trunk/cc4-common/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
[INFO] [13:10:41.963] Execute Findbugs 3.0.0 done: 23902 ms
[INFO] [13:10:42.008] Sensor FindbugsSensor done: 23959 ms
[INFO] [13:10:42.008] Sensor CheckstyleSensor...
[INFO] [13:10:42.017] Execute Checkstyle 5.6...
[INFO] [13:10:42.042] Checkstyle configuration: /srv/build/jenkins/jobs/cc4-trunk/workspace/trunk/cc4-common/target/sonar/checkstyle.xml
[ERROR] Can not execute Checkstyle
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 48.949 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-13T13:10:42+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/286M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project cc4-common: Can not execute Checkstyle: unable to read /srv/build/jenkins/jobs/cc4-trunk/workspace/trunk/cc4-common/target/sonar/checkstyle.xml - unable to parse configuration stream - The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.:1:223 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

In fact, the generated checkstyle.xml is faulty because it contains "<\?xml" and "<\module" twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd"><!-- Generated by Sonar --><module name="Checker"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<!--
    This configuration file was written by the eclipse-cs plugin configuration editor
-->
<!--
    Checkstyle-Configuration: CheckStyle configuration from the Maven parent
    Description: none
-->
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
...
```

For analysis I uploaded this file:
 - checkstyle.xml: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54665247/checkstyle.xml

Doing Google research I found nothing.
Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: just open the uploaded xml in your browser and it will show you the problem: **error on line 1 at column 207: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document**

Comment: I know that the XML is invalid, but it's created during the build, so I can't fix it directly (or manually). How can I prevent the Maven build from creating the broken checkstyle.xml?

Comment: Can you confirm version `2.1.1` of [sonar checkstyle plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Checkstyle+Plugin) is being used?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Sonar Checkstyle Plugin 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It seems that old, migrated data caused the problem: I'm using Sonar since several years, starting off with version 3.1. Every once in a while I upgraded to the current version, thereby migrating my existing sonar MySql database. The last upgrade was from 3.7.4 to 4.5. It seems that the XML header of the originally imported checkstyle.xml (referencing http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd) was added to but not replaced by the current XML header (referencing "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd), resulting in two XML headers and thus invalid XML.

I solved my problem by deleting the affected project in SonarQube. The price of this action is that I lost all of my historical data of the past few years.